# Error with pandas dataframe (needs to be 1-dimensional)

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression, pandas

I am trying to determine the conformal predictions for my model with my data. But it gives me following error that occurs at  icp.calibrate(X_cal, y_cal) :

```
Exception: Data must be 1-dimensional
```

Below you can find the most recent traceback error about this. Unfortunately I am not sure on what this actually infers based on the code from above. I am using a pandas dataframe for this.

#Code Snippet

```
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor
from nonconformist.cp import IcpRegressor
from nonconformist.base import RegressorAdapter
from nonconformist.nc import RegressorNc, AbsErrorErrFunc, RegressorNormalizer, NcFactory
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Setup training, calibration and test data
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
df = pd.read_csv ("prepared_data.csv")


# Initial split into train/test data
train = df.loc[df['split']== 'train']
valid = df.loc[df['split']== 'valid']

# Proper Validation Set (Split the Validation set into features and target)
X_valid = valid.drop(['expression'], axis = 1)
y_valid = valid.drop(columns = ['new_host', 'split', 'sequence'])

# Create Training Set (Split the Training set into features and target)
X_train = valid.drop(['expression'], axis = 1)
y_train = valid.drop(columns = ['new_host', 'split', 'sequence'])

# Split Training set into further training set and calibration set
X_train, X_cal, y_train, y_cal = train_test_split(X_train, y_train, test_size =0.2)

# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Train and calibrate underlying model
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
underlying_model = RegressorAdapter(DecisionTreeRegressor(min_samples_leaf=5))
print("Underlying model loaded")
model = RegressorAdapter(underlying_model)
nc = RegressorNc(model, AbsErrorErrFunc())

print("Nonconformity Function Applied")
icp = IcpRegressor(nc)  # Create an inductive conformal Regressor
print("ICP Regressor Created")

#Dataset Review
print('{} instances, {} features, {} classes'.format(y_train.size,
                                                   X_train.shape[1],
                                                   np.unique(y_train).size))

icp.fit(X_train, y_train)
icp.calibrate(X_cal, y_cal)
```

#Example Dataframe

```
new_host  split     sequence    expression
FALSE     train     AQVPYGVS    0.039267878
FALSE     train     ASVPYGVSI   0.039267878
FALSE     train     STNLYGSGR   0.261456561
FALSE     valid     NLYGSGLVR   0.265188519
FALSE     valid     SLGPSNLYG   0.419680588
FALSE     valid     ATSLGTTNG   0.145710993
```

I've tried splitting the dataset in various ways but I am continuing to have trouble with this. In this case I want to split the data into train and test sets according to an observation's Data Split value. After which, I will split the train set into train and calibration in a second step. Where myfeatures, X_train and my target, y_train

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that this question is better off on stackoverflow.

Nevertheless, `X_cal` gets generated from `X_train` and `X_train` from `valid`. But this is an atleast 2-dimensional dataframe with `new_host` and `sequence`. Like the error says you should only input data that is 1-dimensional.